# Xamarin forms : How to get a value of Entry Text from another content page

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am learning xamaring forms,

I would like to get an Entry text from another xaml.cs file

Here my Entry in my first xaml file (content page) :

```
<Entry x:Name="UserName" Text=""  Placeholder="enter your name"  />
```

And in my second  content page I would like to get the value : `UserName.Text`

I would like to use  [BindableProprety](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) because I am using [this Popup plugin](https://github.com/baskren/Rg.Plugins.Popup/blob/master/README.md), if there is another solution I ll take

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it creating a `PopupPage` because you're using [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rg.Plugins.Popup), place an `Entry` and send an event when user press a button.

I have created an small demo.

**1. The ask user name popup page.**

XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    x:Class="xamstack.AskUserPopupPage"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Padding="20"
        VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
        <Entry x:Name="UserEntry"/>
        <Button Text="Submit" Clicked="ButtonSubmitUser_OnClicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class AskUserPopupPage : PopupPage
{
    public AskUserPopupPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonSubmitUser_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnUserSubmitted(UserEntry.Text);
    }

    public event EventHandler<string> UserSubmitted;
    protected virtual void OnUserSubmitted(string e)
    {
        UserSubmitted?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

**2. Finally the ViewModel and the Page to display/ask the user name.**

ViewModel:

```
public class UserPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _userName;

    public string UserName
    {
        get => _userName;
        set
        {
            if (_userName != value)
            {
                _userName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UserName));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Page XAML:

```
...
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <UserPageViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="{Binding UserName,Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <Button Text="Ask user" Clicked="ButtonAskUser_OnClicked"/>
</StackLayout>
...
```

Page code behind:

```
public partial class UserPage : ContentPage
{
    public UserPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void ButtonAskUser_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var page = new AskUserPopupPage();
        page.UserSubmitted += async (_, userName) =>
        {
            var vm = (UserPageViewModel) BindingContext;
            vm.UserName = userName;
            await Navigation.PopPopupAsync();
        };
        await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(page);
    }
}
```